# Combine GPT3 with RASA

Tags: python, rasa, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to integrate rasa with gpt3, but not getting the proper response. Can help me out to look at my code and tell me issue.

```
def gpt3(text):
response = openai.Completion.create(
    model="code-cushman-001",
    # engine="ada",
    prompt="\n\n" + text,
    temperature=0,
    logprobs=10,
    max_tokens=150,
    top_p=0,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=[" \n\n"]
) 
return response['choices'][0]['text']
```

action.py

```
class ActionDefaultFallback(Action):
def init(self):
    # self.gpt3 = gpt3()
    super()._init_()

def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_default_fallback"

async def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    query = tracker.latest_message['text']
    dispatcher.utter_message(text=gpt3(query))

    return [UserUtteranceReverted()]
```

Not able to understand the issue. Help me out to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is resolved. In case someone following-up on this. Since the exact error is not provided not sure answer is correct but I was able to work this with very little modification to above code.

```
def gpt3(text):
 try:
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        # model="text-davinci-003",
        model="text-ada-001",
        prompt="\n\n" + text + "?",
        temperature=0,
        logprobs=10,
        max_tokens=100,
        top_p=0,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=[" \n\n"]
    )

    return response['choices'][0]['text']
 except Exception as e:
    logger.error('openai request failed')
```

actions.py

```
class ActionDefaultFallback(Action):
 def init(self):
    super().__init__()

 def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_default_fallback"

 async def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
    query = tracker.latest_message['text']
    return dispatcher.utter_message(text=gpt3(query))
```